# Configure LDAP in Spring Boot with Wildfly

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, wildfly

I'm working on a Spring Boot app using Maven and Wildfly 11 and I need my users to authenticate with the company's LDAP. This configuration is located at the Wildfly server, in the standalone.xml, and it is shared by all the applications in the company. I've been reading many tutorials but I don't know how to configure my app to authenticate against the LDAP without using web.xml or configuring the LDAP data on the Java classes, because I need to take it from the standalone.xml like the rest of the apps. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly has support for LDAP authentication. Search for Elytron Ldap Realm. E.g. [1][2]

[1]http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/configuring-ldap-based-authentication-with-elytron-on-wildfly
[2]https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Using+the+Elytron+Subsystem#UsingtheElytronSubsystem-ConfigureAuthenticationwithanLDAPBasedIdentityStore